# fast windows marshaling between 32-bit and 64-bit processes

Tags: windows, ipc, marshalling, 32bit-64bit

Currently app structure is as follows:

- Our C# GUI
- Our managed C++ library
- 3rd-party unmanaged 32-bit C++ library

What we need is to make our application 64-bit but leave 3rd-party library 32-bit (there is no 64-bit version). The issue is that this library is decoding large arrays (10-100 MB) all the time, so marshaling time is an issue.

Few options that we thought of:

1. Wrap 3rd-party library into Managed C++ ActiveX and call it from C# - simple, but we expect heavy marshaling penalties
2. Use Boost.Interprocess at both sides - seems to be more complex, but probably faster

Any suggestions regarding which way to choose for sake of execution speed? Are there other ways?

Comment: Use a memory mapped file.

Comment: I need to call several functions asynchronously, so MMF seems to be quite complex to implement